# Output every nth byte of stdin

Tags: python, unix, io

What's the easiest efficient way to read from stdin and output every nth byte?
I'd like a command-line utility that works on OS X, and would prefer to avoid [compiled languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394479/fastest-way-to-read-every-30th-byte-of-large-binary-file).

This Python script is fairly slow (25s for a 3GB file when n=100000000):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
n = int(sys.argv[1])
while True:
    chunk = sys.stdin.read(n)
    if not chunk:
        break
    sys.stdout.write(chunk[0])
```

Unfortunately we can't use `sys.stdin.seek` to avoid reading the entire file.

Edit: I'd like to optimize for the case when n is a significant fraction of the file size. For example, I often use this utility to sample 500 bytes at equally-spaced locations from a large file.

Comment: How long does it take to just read the 3GB file on your system? (Making sure it's not in the disk cache when you time this.)

Comment: Reading the entire file is slow, but I'm interested in the case where n is large. For example, I'd like to sample 500 bytes from a binary file.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily add much. For example, reading every 500th byte of a file on a magnetic disk would quite likely be just as slow as reading the entire file.

Comment: I'm on an SSD, so hopefully I can do better. Note that I only want to read 500 bytes at equally-spaced locations -- not every 500th byte.

Comment: Does the file have to be fed through stdin? Can you access it directly instead?

Comment: stdin is preferred, but I'd consider a file-based approach if necessary.

Comment: In which case, use a file and `seek()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE**: OP change the example n from 100 to 100000000 which effectively render my code slower than his, normally i would just delete my answer since it is no longer better than the original example, but my answer gotten a vote so i will just leave it as it is.

---

the only way that i can think of to make it faster is to read everything at once and use slice

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
n = int(sys.argv[1])
data = sys.stdin.read()
print(data[::n])
```

although, trying to fit a 3GB file into the ram might be a very bad idea

Comment: What are your reasons for thinking this would be faster than the original?

Comment: you wouldn't be calling read and checking if not chunk on every loop

Comment: That would only help if that is where the bottleneck is and it's almost certainly somewhere else (disk I/O).

Comment: on my 4.9MB test case, it's 42 times faster and on my 49.7MB test case, it's 129 times faster, the reason i tried this was cause i notice that on the original code, my cpu was max out (100%), although, i pass 5 as the nth so it was reading every 5 bytes on the original code

Comment: Unfortunately this is slower on my 3GB file with n=100000000 (a more realistic value for my purposes).

Comment: @tba, that would make it every 100MB, it is far from your 500 bytes :/

Comment: "500 bytes at equally-spaced locations", not "every 500th byte"

Comment: but your example is outputting every nth bytes