# Iterate over 10GB+ binary file

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

What is the simplest way to read a 10GB binary file and parse each byte without resorting to boost libraries?

Its so confusing with streams, files, memory mapped files etc.

I literally just want something like:

```
char* buffer = read(filename, binary);

while(buffer != EOF){
    //Read byte
    ++buffer;
}
```

Performance does matter simply due to the file size.

Comment: What's wrong with std::ifstream?

Comment: For simple chunks i always fall back to C and unbuffered  FILE* handling.

Comment: memory mapped file is the best.

Comment: @Jichao: Why do you say memory mapped file is the best?

Comment: @Jichao Define 'best', and state your reasons. Memory mapping this file is a way to waste 10GB of virtual memory when reading 4-8k at a time is possibly quite adequate.

Comment: According to [my experience](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171625/how-to-scan-through-really-huge-files-on-disk), maybe memory mapped file is the fastest way to do this.

Comment: @Jichao (1) The OP specifically said performance wasn't a concern; (2) does your experience include 10GB files?

Comment: *"Its so confusing with streams, files, memory mapped files etc."* - You will have to try it yourself and bechmark them, then use the fastest in your platform. Libraries, OS, compilers, Memories{Disks, SSDs, RAM etc}, DMA implementations etc are still evolving in ways that makes certain things faster... We are no longer in the days where we can arbitrarily tell you which is fastest without seeing actual implementations

Comment: @EJP (1) `Performance does matter` (2) for sequential access, memory mapped files should be the fastest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want good performance for sequential access (reading from the beginning toward the end), use [`fread()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/).  You can store the `FILE*` in a `std::shared_ptr` for RAII:

```
std::shared_ptr<FILE> file(fopen(...), fclose);
```

You can ignore C++ streams, memory mapped files, Boost, etc.  None of that will be faster than `fread()`.

Comment: *"None of that will be faster than `fread()`"* - We need evidence for this kind of [ipsedixitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipse_dixit). Got some numbers to back up your statement?

Comment: @WhiZTiM: I have tested these things many times.  Anyone who wants to be 100% sure about their particular use case on their particular platform is welcome to write their own benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

As you aren't concerned with performance,
a simple while loop with `ifstream` can extract one byte at a time:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){

  std::ifstream infile("file.txt");

  while (infile){

    //get next byte
    char c;
    infile.get(c);

    //process byte
    std::cout << c;
  }

}
```

Comment: Surely you would not read a 10 GB input file one byte at a time.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Why not? The code that's doing the actual I/O for you knows better and will read efficiently-sized chunks as needed unless you explicitly tell it not to do that. I can imagine plenty of applications that would demand reading byte by byte.

Comment: @xaxxon Words. Does "best algorithm" suit you better?